# Build a dynamic data validation list from several named ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have several values placed in several cells as follows. I have already defined named ranges: `name1` for D3, `name2` for F3, `name3` for J3, `name4` for N3.

Now, I would like to make a cell with data validation; values in its dropdown list are `v1`, `v2`, `v3` and `v4`.

I would like the source of this data validation to be based on named ranges `name1`, `name2`, `name3` and `name4`. As a result,

1. Even though the location of the cells changes, as long as the named ranges are correct, we are sure that the dropdown list could contain correct values.
2. We could modify the values in the named ranges, and the values in the dropdown list are automatically updated.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

[image]

**Edit 1:**

To make this question less hard, let's assume that all these named ranges are always in Row `3`, and Row `3` does not have other data. I tried to define another named range `all` with `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($3:$3,$3:$3<>""))`, As a result, `=all` in a cell did return  all the values.

However, I wrote `=all` in the source of data validation, it returned `The Source currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue?`. Clicking on `Yes` returned an empty dropdown list.

[image]

I guess maybe it is because Source of data validation does not work well with dynamic array functions like `FILTER`. Does anyone have another formula (to remove blanks in a list) with traditional functions to try?

Comment: you will need a helper column in which you have the four named ranges stacked and then refer to that range.

Comment: Is it possible to not display this helper column in sheets (eg, only define it in the Name Manager)?

Comment: no, it must be in the sheet.  But you could put it off in a column that is off the screen.

Comment: or you could put it on a very hidden sheet that the user cannot see.

Comment: In response to your edit.  Data Validation/conditional formatting have never worked with array type formula.  It has been widely publicized as a "flaw" and yet Microsoft in all their wisdom did not "fix" this issue when they introduced dynamic arrays.  So no, there is no formula that will do this directly.  You will need to use a helper column to do what you want.

Comment: One option would be, if the cells are manually maintained, one can use vba in a worksheet_change event and "hard code" the list in the data validation directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a seperate location (maybe like a 'system' tab) to 'store' the temp list data. It can be done like this:

Use a filter to remove the empty cells like this:

```
=FILTER(D3:N3,D3:N3<>""))
```

Then transpose that output to make it a vertical list:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(D3:N3,D3:N3<>""))
```

This is now a dynamic list of your values. Now think about how large this list could be in the future. Currently it is 4 values, so let's assume 10. Reserve up to 10 cells for this dynamic list to allow it to grow. Now use these 10 cells as input for your dropdown-list.